# Make all accounts use the same kind of Bash

Tags: linux, ssh, bash, shell, users

On a dedicated server we use the shell is setup differently between accounts, which is quite irritating. When I `ssh` into most users I get:

```
[user@machine some_dir]$
```

However, with some accounts I get:

```
bash-3.2$
```

I keep a lot of shells open to various machines, and there are a lot of different accounts. I have the ability to either make everyone have the same `~/.bashrc`, but I also believe there is a global config somewhere in `/etc`

What's the fastest way to make sure I get the same shell whenever I `ssh`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is a mix of the two approaches.  Bash will always load `~/.bashrc`.  You should place a standard file in `/etc/skel/.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc` that in turn sources something like `/etc/bash.bashrc`.  (The version in `skel` will get used for new user accounts.)  Put your defaults in the latter file.

Example user `.bashrc`:

```
# this line activates the system-wide default settings
. /etc/bash.bashrc

# users can add any custom .bashrc settings here
```

Example `/etc/bash.bashrc` based on my prompt:

```
G='\e[1;32m'
R='\e[1;31m'
Y='\e[1;33m'
N='\e[0m'
PS1='\A \['$G'\]\u@\h \['$Y'\]\w\['$N'\] \$ '
```

With this setup, you can later change the system-wide prompt and add other settings without having to edit everybody's `.bashrc` file.  Hope that helps.

Comment: This would be horrible to maintain. If you wanted to change system-wide performance later, you would have to modify each individual .bashrc  in the user's home directory. You're also recreating existing native performance. Finally, .bashrc is for non-login shells. .bash_profile is for login shells.  See `INVOCATION` in the manpage.

Comment: Where can I find the settings that are being used for other accounts?

Comment: Warner: No, it wouldn't be a problem to maintain.  I specifically set it up so that you can just edit /etc/bash.bashrc after you are done to change system-wide behavior.  Also, I know about the login vs. non-login issue and chose bashrc specifically; if you set the prompt in `.bash_profile`, it will not apply to non-login xterms, because they don't have any login shell in the parent processes.  Ideally, `.bash_profile` or `/etc/profile` should source `~/.bashrc` so that the prompt settings apply to *all* interactive shells.

Comment: @Krisropher: I don't understand your question.  Every account works the same: Non-login interactive shells (xterms, shells in GNU screen, etc.) read `~/.bashrc`.  Login shells (SSH or terminal logins) will instead read `/etc/profile` and then the first of `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login` or `~/.profile` that exists; oftentimes one of those will source the user's `~/.bashrc` so that settings in `.bashrc` apply to all interactive shells as I mention in my previous comment.

Comment: @Warner: One more point, in reply to your statement that I am recreating existing native functions.  AFAIK, there is no system-wide file that all interactive shells read on startup.  Login shells read `/etc/profile` but non-login interactive shells only read `~/.bashrc`, so everything important has to go in the latter in my experience, or that file has to include something system-wide.

Comment: You have a point in that bash doesn't have the support natively.  However, RHEL based distributions do exactly what you describe using the `/etc/bashrc` file.

Comment: @Walter Mundt answered my question excellently

Answer (score 2):

`/etc/profile` is the standard location for the system-wide bash configuration on most systems.

From the [bash manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

```
PROMPTING
       When executing interactively, bash displays the primary prompt PS1 when
       it  is  ready  to  read a command, and the secondary prompt PS2 when it
       needs more input to complete  a  command.
```

Comment: /etc/profile is the best place to put this for login shells, use /etc/bash.bashrc as well for nonlogin shells.